# When the Web HTML interpreter read the code under the script tag?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, web

I have a script inserted on the head of the page like this

```
<head>
   ... load jQuery ....
   <script>var bbody = $('body');</script>
</head>
<body>
  ....

   <script>console.log(bbody);</script>
   <script>console.log($('body'));</script>
</body>
```

And always the result of the console.log in the first sentence it's `undefined`, but the second it's the correct object, So my question is:

1. ¿Always the code on the `<script>` is executed at the moment on the interpreter read the code inside in?

Comment: b/c that point of time body was not available .

Comment: Yes, it synchronous (Unless you load a js file with `defer`/`async` - Then the browser will render the content and only then load the script, when you use `defer` you can trust that the scripts will execute in the same order)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu something this basic ... you know it has to have been asked many many times though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hierarchical. The `<body>` is still not in picture, for the first `<script>` tag. So, `undefined`.

You can use `$(document).ready` to define your `bbody` to make sure the dom loads first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bbody = $('body');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `var bbody = $('body');` in a `$(document).ready` to make sure that the body tag exists when you want to load it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bbody = $('body');
});
```